# Multivariable chain rule and Jacobian

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule, jacobian

**Let f : $R^3$ → $R^2$ be given by f(r, s, t) = ($r^3$s + $t^2$, rst). Let g : $R^2$ → $R^{11}$ and h : $R^{11}$ → $R^4$ be two differentiable functions. 
Compute $J_{h◦g◦f}$ (0, 21, 0).**

I've tried the question and now I'm stuck, this is what I have done so far.

**Current workings :**

$J_{h◦g◦f}$ = $J_{h}(g(f(r,s,t)))$ ⋅ $J_{g}(f(r,s,t))$ ⋅ $J_{f}(r,s,t)$

f(r,s,t) = $\begin{bmatrix}f_1(r,s,t)\\f_2(r,s,t)\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}r^3s + t^2\\rst\end{bmatrix}$

$J_f$ = $\begin{bmatrix}3r^2s & r^3 & 2t\\st & rt & rs\end{bmatrix}$

I understand that my next step should be finding the Jacobians of $J_g$ and $J_h$. Using these individual matrices, I can multiply them and find $J_{g◦f}$ and $J_{h◦g◦f}$.

But I'm not sure how to find $J_g$ and $J_h$ because I don't know how to express them in terms of r,s,t.

Any help please?

Comment: There's some formatting issues here; aht do you mean by $R^11$? is it $\mathbb{R}^{11}$? or just a typo for $\mathbb{R}^1=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Kevin yeap thanks

Comment: Find the Jacobian with respect to different variables.  Then plug in $g\circ f$ or $f$ after computing the Jacobian.

Comment: @MichaelBurr so you mean I should use dummy variables to compute jacobian of g and h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $J_f=
\begin{pmatrix}
3r^2s & r^3 & 2t\\st & rt & rs
\end{pmatrix}$ evaluated at $(0,21,0)$ is the $(2\times 3)$ $0$-matrix.

> We conclude, that $J_{h\circ g\circ f}$ evaluated at $(0,21,0)$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
> J_{h\circ g\circ f}(0,21,0)
> &=J_{h}(g(f(0,21,0)))\cdot J_{g}(f(0,21,0)) \cdot J_{f}(0,21,0)\\
> &=J_{h}(g(f(0,21,0)))\cdot J_{g}(f(0,21,0))\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
> 0& 0& 0\\0& 0& 0
> \end{pmatrix}\\
> &=(0)_{{1\leq j\leq 4}\atop{1\leq k\leq 11}}
> \end{align*}
>
> the $(4\times 11)$ $0$-matrix.

Comment: wow I did figure out that $J_f$ is the (2×3)  0-matrix but I thought that was a wrong move. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo: You're welcome.